# mat-autocomplete key value filter issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material autocomplete to filter data, each option has name and value.

this is my hml code:

```
<mat-form-field [appearance]="appearance">
  <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
  <input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.value" >
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

and my .ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.options);
this.filteredOptions = this.autoCompleteControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(value => this.filter(value))
  );
}

private filter(value: string): string[] {
 console.log(value)
 const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
 return this.options.filter(option => option.key.includes(filterValue));
}
```

the filter function is called after every filtering and works fine

my problem is after selecting an option the value that gets by this.autoCompleteControl.valueChanges
is the numeric value of the option and not the string name so it throws an exception:

*value.toLowerCase is not a function*

any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing [value] as `option.value`, you can pass `option`, and change the filter and displayFunction

```
<mat-form-field [appearance]="appearance">
  <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
  <input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in the component

```
displayFn(option){
  if(option && option.name) {
    return option.name.toLowerCase();
  } else {
    return option
  }
}

private filter(value: string): string[] {
   console.log(value)
   const filterValue = value.name.toLowerCase();
   return this.options.filter(option => option.key.includes(filterValue));
}
```

Comment: this is my updated filer function:
    if(value.key){
      const filterValue = value.key.toLowerCase();
      return this.options.filter(option => option.key.includes(filterValue));
    }
    else{
      const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
      return this.options.filter(option => option.key.includes(filterValue));

Answer (score 1):

In HTML page, Use `[value]="option"` instead of `[value]="option.value"` as like

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option" >
  {{option.name}}
</mat-option>
```

And In **.ts** file, add the below code as follow

```
private filter(value: any): any[] {
 console.log(value)
 const filterValue = value.name.toLowerCase();
 return this.options.filter(option => option.key.includes(filterValue));
}
```

Comment: thanks, worked for me with the addition of displayFn

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `value` attribute of `option` will be set when you select an option. You can change that value to name.

```
<mat-form-field [appearance]="appearance">
  <mat-label>{{label}}</mat-label>
  <input type="text" aria-label="Number" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option.name" > // change value to name
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: i need this value to identify the option